# Metric Spaces: Explore the relationship between $\partial_P S$ and $\partial_{X_{i}} \pi_i(S)$ for $i \in \mathbb N_n.$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Suppose $n \in \mathbb N$ and, for each $i \in  \mathbb N_n$, $(X_i, \tau_i)$ is a non-empty metric space. Suppose $d$ is a conserving metric on $P = \prod_{i=1}^n X_i$. Suppose
$S \subseteq P$. Explore the relationship between $\partial_P S$ and $\partial_{X_i} \pi_i(S)$ for $i ∈ \mathbb  N_n.$

Note that $\partial_P S$ refers to the boundary of $S$ in $P$. $\pi_i(S)$ refers to the $i$th natural projection of $S$ into $X_i$.
$\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ refers to the product tupple.

**The definition of a conserving metric is attached at the bottom**

**Attempt:**

> > $\partial_P S= \{x \in P \mid dist(x,S)=0=dist(x, S^C) \} \qquad \qquad(1)$.
> >
> > $\partial_{X_i} \pi_i(S) = \{x_i \in X_i \mid dist(~x_i, ~\pi_i(S)~)=0=dist(~x_i, ~\pi_i^c(S)~)\} \qquad \qquad  (2)$.

Also, since $d$ is conserving :

> > $\max \{\tau_i(a_i,b_i) \mid i \in N_n \} \le d(a,b) \le \sum_{i=1}^n \tau_i(a_i,b_i) \qquad \qquad (3)$

By definition: $dist (x,S)= \inf \{d(x,s) \mid s \in S\}$. Therefore, by the definition of infimum, we have,

> > $\forall~ r >0, \exists \ s_r \in S \mid d(x,s_r)<dist (x,S)+r \qquad\qquad\qquad(4)$

Now, suppose $x \in \partial_P S$. Then, $x$ satisfies $(1)$.
Then, due to inequality $(3)$ and $(4)$, we have :

$~\tau_i(x_i, ~\pi_i~(S)~)=0=~\tau_i(x_i, ~\pi_i^c~(S)~) \qquad \forall \ i \in  \mathbb N_n$

This clearly means that whenever $x$ belongs to $\partial_P S,$ then $x_i ~\in~ \partial_{X_i} \pi_i(S) \quad \forall~ i\in N_n$.

Similarly, we can prove the other way around as well.

> > However, my textbook Metric Spaces by Michael Searcoid presents the solution as below. The solution is a contradiction to our above analysis. **Could anyone please help me understand if my analysis is wrong or in an unlikely situation, the solution could be completely wrong?** Thank you very much!

[image]

[image]

> > ---

[image]

[image]

> > **_Proving the other way around**

Suppose $x_i \in \partial_{X_i} \pi_i(S)~~\forall~~i \in \mathbb N~$ where $~x_i \in X_i$.

$\implies dist(x_i, \pi_i(S))=0=dist(x_i~,~(~ \pi_i(S)~)^c)~\forall~i \in \mathbb N$

$dist(x_i, \pi_i(S))=0~~\forall~~i \in \mathbb N$

$\implies \forall~ r>0, ~ \exists~ s_{ir} \in \pi_i(S)~|~\tau_i(x_i,s_{ir}) < \frac {r}{n}$

By definition of a conserving metric: we have $d(a,b) \le \sum_{i=1}^n \tau_i(a_i,b_i)$

$\implies d(x,s_r)<r~$ where $~s_r \in S$ as each $s_{ir} \in \pi_i(S)$ and $x \in P$ as $x_i \in X_i$.

$\implies dist(x,S)=0 \quad \quad \quad (1)$.

**Similarly**: $dist(x_i~,~(~ \pi_i(S)~)^c)=0~\forall~i \in \mathbb N$

$\implies \forall~ r>0, ~ \exists~ s'_{icr} \in (~\pi_i(S)~)^c~|~\tau_i(x_i,~s'_{icr}~) < \frac {r}{n}~\forall~ i \in \mathbb N_n~$

where each $~s'_{icr} \in (~ \pi_i(S)~)^c$.

By definition of a conserving metric: we have $d(x,s'_{cr}) \le \sum_{i=1}^n \tau_i(x_i,~s'_{icr}~)$

$\implies d(x,s'_{cr}) \le r~$ where $~s'_{cr} \in~ S^c$ as each $~s'_{icr} \in (~ \pi_i(S)~)^c$.

$\implies dist(x,S^c)=0 \quad \quad \quad (2)$

from $(1),(2)$, we have $ dist(x,S^c)=0= dist(x,S) $

which means $x \in \partial_P S$.

What could be the error which has made in this proof here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Explore the relationship between $\partial_P S$ and $\partial_{X_i} \pi_i(S)$ for $i \in \mathbb  N_n.$

As I have understood, you question is only about a particular problem.

Also,  as I have understood given a point $t\in P$ by $t_i$ you denote $\pi_i(t)$.

The error is here:

> $~\tau_i(x_i, ~\pi_i~(S)~)=0=~\tau_i(x_i, ~\pi_i^c~(S)~)$

Whereas the first equality follows from the fact that $\tau_i(x_i, s_{ri})<r$, for the second the situation is different, because if $s_r^c$ be a point in $S^c$ such that $d(x,s^c_r)<r$ then $s_{ri}$ is contained in $\pi_i(S^c)$, but not necessarily in $\pi^c_i(S)$ (which I understood as $\pi_i(S)^c$). The later set may be empty.
As I understood, this possibility is illustrated by the second part of Q 3.11.

The other way around is even worse. Let $n=2$ and $x_i\in\partial_PS$ for each $i$. 
Then for each positive $r$ there exist points $(s_{r1}, s_{r2})$ and $(s’_{r1}, s’_{r2})\in P$ such that $\tau_1(x_1, s_{r1})<r$ and $\tau_2(x_2, s’_{r2})<r$. But this does not imply that there exists a point $(s^*_{r1},s^*_{r2})\in P$ such that $\tau_i(x_i, s^*_{ri})<r$ for each $i$. This possibility is illustrated by the first part of Q 3.11.

Comment: thank you for answering. I think I get what you're saying. Hope I can get back to you in case I have any query. Thanks again!

Comment: If we consider the subset $U=\{ n, \frac {1}{n} \}$ in $\mathbb R^2$, then it's the same as sketching the graph of $xy=1$ but only at integer points. The graph's elements are  at $0$ distance from $U$ as well as  from $U^c = \mathbb R^2- \{U\}$. then, shouldn't the elements of $U$ be considered as boundary of $U$?

Comment: @Wanderer Yes, each of the sets $\{(n,1/n):n\in\Bbb N\}$ and $\{(x,y):xy=1\}$ its a boudary of itself.

Comment: ok :-) . One more question which I got was that in the second part of $3.11$ -  they defined $S= (\mathbb R^+   \times \mathbb R^-) ~\cup ~(\mathbb R^- \times \mathbb R^+).$. Isn't it the same as saying $S=\mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R^-$. Also, they have said $(0,0) \in S$. But, $S$ is clearly the cartesion product of positive $\mathbb R$ and negative $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Wanderer I have understood their notation such that $\Bbb R^\oplus=\{x\in\Bbb R: x\ge 0\}$, $\Bbb R^\ominus=\{x\in\Bbb R: x\le 0\}$, and their products  are considered as subspaces of $\Bbb R^2$. So $S$  is a union of the second and fourth quadrants, which clealry contains the origin $(0,0)$.

Comment: @_Alex I have added a section of a proof which I had thought sometime before. it is under the title - Proving the other way around. I get most of your argument which you have made. But, I am unable to spot any error in the proof which I have written at the bottom of my question. Could you please have a final look and guide me. Thank you very much for your patience!

Comment: @Wanderer Conclusion as “where $~s_r \in S$ as each $s_{ir} \in \pi_i(S)$” holds not for general $S$, but for rectangular $S=\prod\pi_i(S)$. A counterexample is again provided by the first part of Q 3.11. The same remark concerns the conclusion “where $~s'_{cr} \in~ S^c$ as each $~s'_{icr} \in (~ \pi_i(S)~)^c$”. Moreover, both $S$ and $S^c$ are rectangular iff there exists $j$ such that $S=\prod_{i<j} X_i\times \pi_j(S)\times \prod_{i>j} X_i$. Also the inclusion $\pi_i(S)^c\subset\pi_i(S^c)$ is true, but if the opposite inclusion holds iff $S=\pi^{-1}_i(\pi_i(S))$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your constructive comments. I got it.